# Firebase and Android, getHttpsCallable how to deserialize json into object

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use firestore for all of my networking in my android app. It works well and out of the box it deserializes into objects for me. Now I need to use an httpsCallable, and I rather not import a new third party library or kotlinx.serizlization in order to deserialize this single call. Is there a way to hook into the deserializing that firestore already seems to have built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anything is built into Firebase for this yet, although it could actually make a reasonable feature request to file on the Github [repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk) of the Firebase Android SDK.

In the meantime the best you is look at the source for the [`DocumentSnapshot.toObject` method](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.java#L175-L184), which delegates most of its work to `CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(data, valueType, getReference())`.

This [`CustomClassMapper` class](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/221f616b1865360777a67016308b90792a153a09/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/CustomClassMapper.java) is also included in the repo, and is `public` (though not included in the public documentation for the SDK), so you might be able to use the class in your own project too.